# Extract substrings defined by positioning relative to other relatively positioned characters

Tags: r, regex, string

I have many URLs in a character vector and I'm trying to extract substrings from them using base R. There are two types of substrings I want to extract:

- The substring after the last slash (/) in the string and before the last underscore (_).
- The substring after the last underscore (_) and before the substring .tar.gz.

I've hacked together a solution to this, but it involves many unecessary steps. Is there a way to accomplish this using a single regex per substring?

Below is my working example:

```
# An example URL
a <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggplot2/ggplot2_0.4.5.tar.gz"

# Keep everything after the last slash
b <- sub('.*\\/', '', a)
# Keep everything before .tar.gaz
c <- sub('.tar.*', '', b)

# Extract desired strings based on underscore
foo <- sub('.*\\_', '', c)
bar <- sub('\\_.*', '', c)
```

It is important for this example to use base R.

Comment: With given example this works: `sub(".tar.*", "", strsplit(basename(a), "_")[[1]])`, but it might not work with more complicated file.

Comment: This is great! I didn't know about basename(). Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution that uses `basename` and `strsplit` at `_`:

```
sub(".tar.*", "", strsplit(basename(a), "_")[[1]])
[1] "ggplot2" "0.4.5"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
regmatches(a, regexpr('(?<=\\/)[^\\/]+(?=_)', a, perl = T))
[1] "ggplot2"
regmatches(a, regexpr('(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\\.tar\\.gz)', a, perl = T))
[1] "0.4.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `\/(?<package>[^\/]+)\_(?<version>[^\_\/]+).tar.gz$`.

In a match, first capturing group, named `package` will give you *The substring after the last slash (/) in the string and before the last underscore (_)* and second, named `version`, will give you *The substring after the last underscore (_) and before the substring .tar.gz.*

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mv8Uxo/1)